# Anniversary of love?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

On 2016/1/27, my current girlfriend agreed to become my girlfriend. So today, or 2017/1/27, is a special day for us. However, I don't know how to name this significant day. I've performed some searching, and found these phrases:

- Our first anniversary of love
- First anniversary of our love
- First anniversary for love
- First love anniversary
- First anniversary
- etc.

Which one is correct? You can also name this day with other phrases or single words.

Comment: I would specifically avoid "our first anniversy of love" and "first anniversary of our love", as there's a sexual connotation to that. Someone might think you're celebrating the anniversary of something else entirely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> One year anniversary

or

> First anniversary

Anniversary can be used in many contexts, although in the context

> My girlfriend and I are celebrating our first anniversary today

it is interpreted as one year since you became a couple.

> My wife and I are celebrating our fifth anniversary today

is interpreted as five years since you married your wife

Comment: I think your first suggestion is the best suggestion, but I would hyphenate it: _one-year anniversary_ (that hyphen appears to be a [preference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one-year+anniversary%2Cone+year+anniversary&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), though, not a requirement).

Answer (score 5):

Fun question, but unfortunately there is no word for this.  You have to make something up, and so it's really just a matter of opinion.  Most people would say something like:

> December 31st is the anniversary of our first date!

My wife just calls this our "date-o-versary".  If it's a different event, modify as appropriate.

Comment: We celebrate getting married in weeks: So on Saturday my husband said "Happy 371st!"

Comment: @WillowRex WOW what an interesting couple you are!

Comment: @SunQingyao Everyone is interesting, don't you think? That's the fun of living. Learning new things, meeting new people, having the next experience, sharing fun and knowledge with others? I am here *because* my grammar is atrocious. I feel this is a great place to learn.